# Cannot install pip on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, installation

I'm a new Python user. I'm having issues installing new modules for `python 2.7`. When I try installing a new module from PyCharm, I get the following error

> Error: Python packaging tool 'pip' not found

Moreover, I'm a bit confuse about which Python version I'm actually using...
This is what I get when I type the following commands in the terminal.

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/
$ python -V
Python 2.7.6
```

Everything seems a bit messed up to me...all the procedures I follow to install pip result in failure. The command

```
$ python get-pip.py
```

returns

> You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.1 is available.
>       You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command

However, when I run that command, it tells me that there is no module named pip.
Please, how can I fix it? I need to work with Python 2.7 but I'm completely unable to install packages. Thanks.

**EDIT** I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Have your tried `python -m pip`?

Comment: Yes, it looks like your Python installations are slightly messed up. Are you using Ubuntu? First, get rid of that PYTHONPATH. It's probably set in your ~/.bashrc. Look for a line that starts `export PYTHONPATH` and comment it out.

Comment: Which linux distribution are you using? Do you have a system package manager installed (i.e. apt-get, yum, etc)?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be trying to install pip wrong. Depending on your version of linux there are several install methods that can be found [here](https://packaging.python.org/install_requirements_linux/)

for your version judging by your use of get.

try this one:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```